# Fastest way to startup Selenium chromedriver: what command line flags to use?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

#### Question:

I'm looking to find the fastest way possible on starting up a Selenium Chrome webdriver, i.e. speeding up this bit of code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I have used headless browser with the following arguments on `ChromeOptions`:

```py
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('--headless')
op.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
op.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
op.binary_location = GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN_PATH

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options = op)
```

Is there a way to make the startup even faster?

I've found list of many command line switches here https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ but I'm not sure which to choose in alignment with what I'm trying to accomplish.

#### Background:

I will need a separate webdriver instance to do something every time a request comes in to my app:

1. A request comes.
2. Webdriver starts.
3. Webdriver does things as specified by the request.
4. Webdriver shuts down.
5. Result is summarized, and a response is sent.

I'm not interested in preparing the webdrivers beforehand. Currently, I'm also unable to use `requests` as an alternative, given the complexity of the webpage I'm interacting with. It's just easier and probably safer to use webdriver. Hence I need to optimize the startup of the webdriver, since it takes the majority of time required to respond to a request.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for the same thing, as far as I found on the web, you can set the driver path (this applies mainly in the undetectedriver case because it downloads the driver each time it is started), you can also provide a path to the chrome profile so tat it doesn't get created each time the browser starts.

Another possibility is to adapt the logic of the program, in my case, it was convenient to keep the driver running and have a loop that checks for new request (then the request needs to be communicated with program that runs the driver in some way, for instance trough an HTTP server or simply through the file system by create a file for each request in some directory and let the driver's program deletes it after it executed the request inside it). Having the driver running in a docker is also an option, but this doesn't bring a lot in terms of speed of driver startup compared to having it running the the host machine.

It may be a good idea also to open an issue on Github asking for a recommendation to achieve a faster startup. One other possibility that requires more manoeuvre is to switch to another browser emulation framework such as cypress or playwright/puppeteer.

Another way to go is to test different chrome browser implementations/versions, here is a list of different Google chrome release channels: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/. I got a faster startup with the `beta` channel. It might be interesting to test older versions but I couldn't find an official list of links for them, this may bring new html/css/3rd-parties compatibility issues; basically the effort to invest in investigating this further is relative to the importance/benefit of the tool to develop.